# Second bean action method via <f:actionListener binding> not invoked

Tags: jsf, actionlistener, commandlink

I want to call two bean methods from `<h:commandlink>`. I am using following code,

```
<h:commandLink value="Mounts" action="#{frameSizer.goToMounts(2)}" rendered="#{not singleTab.max() and not(singleTab.imaging)}">
    <f:actionListener binding="#{frameSizer.updatesizes()}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

But `frameSizer.updatesizes()` method is not called. I have to call this method before `frameSizer.goToMounts(2)` method. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I think you forgot something ;)

Comment: It was initially invisible because you didn't pay attention and love to the message preview and/or message formatting rules. See also the edit history by clicking on "edited" link here above.